# Issues sorting by two attributes

Tags: magento-1, collection, product-list, sorting

I'm having problems applying a default sort order to the product collection for the listing page. When some conditions are met I want to sort by 'region' and then by 'price'. I have added the following in app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php.

```
  public function setCollection($collection)
{
    $this->_collection = $collection;

    $this->_collection->setCurPage($this->getCurrentPage());
    $limit = (int)$this->getLimit();
    if ($limit) {
        $this->_collection->setPageSize($limit);
    }
    if(Mage::registry('current_category')->getName() == 'France'){
        $this->_collection->setOrder(array('region', 'price'), $this->getCurrentDirection());
    }else{
        if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
            $this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

This sorts by region successfully but not by price. I did read somewhere that different resources are used by price than other attributes when using them for sorting. If this is the case it makes sense because when I substituted price with name - `$this->_collection->setOrder(array('region','name'), 'asc');` I get the collection sorted by region and then by name.

To confirm, both attributes are set yes to - Used in Product Listing and Used for Sorting in Product Listing.
Any suggestions on getting price to work with region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` as @DavidManners suggested I eventually found a solution that appears to work

```
   $this->_collection->getSelect()->order(array('region', 'price_index.final_price'), $this->getCurrentDirection());
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that there are some special code that needs to be run to sort by price.

If you take a look into the function `setOrder` on the model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` you will see that it does something "special" when dealing with the attribute price.

```
public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = 'desc')
{
    if ($attribute == 'price') {
        $this->addAttributeToSort($attribute, $dir);
    } else {
        parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

My suggestion for you is to follow this example and try adding the sort by price in the same fashion and by calling `addAttributeToSort`.

Comment: hey thanks for the answer. I've won't have a chance to really look at it for a while but so far even knowing that price needs a different filter function using it with another filter is complicated. Thanks again tho, hopefully it will set me right!